# Android Mockito Test on View Model method with MutableLiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, mocking, mockito, android-testing

I am new to the Mockito Android Test framework and I am following MVVM architecture and I have one method in the view model which updates the live data object and I need to write test cases for that method but I am getting errors.

Here is my ViewModel method:

This method updates the MutableLiveData value.

```
fun showProgressBar(
        shortMessage: String?,
        longMessage: String?,
        progress: Int,
        status: String?
    ) {
        val cdfw = Cdfw()
        Log.info("status --> " + status)
        if(status.equals(ConstantsStrings.IN_PROGRESS,true)){
            Log.info("IN_PROGRESS status --> " + status)
            cdfw.isNeedToShow = true
            cdfw.isNeedToShowCloseButton = false
        }else{
            cdfw.isNeedToShow = true
            Log.info("isNeedToShowCloseButton --> " + status)
            cdfw.isNeedToShowCloseButton = true
        }
        shortMessage?.let {
            cdfw.shortMessage = shortMessage
        }
        longMessage?.let {
            cdfw.longMessage = longMessage
        }
        status?.let {
            cdfw.status = status
        }
        cdfw.percentage = progress
        cdfwData.value = cdfw
    }
```

Here cdfwData look like inside viewmodel:

```
val cdfwData = MutableLiveData<Cdfw>().apply {
        value = Cdfw()
    }

var cdfw: MutableLiveData<Cdfw> = cdfwData
```

How my test classes look like:

```
@Test
    public void testCdfwInProgress() {
        ActivityMainViewModel activityMainViewModel = Mockito.mock(ActivityMainViewModel.class);

        activityMainViewModel.showProgressBar("123", "123", 10,
                "IN_PROGRESS");

        Assert.assertSame(true,activityMainViewModel.getCdfw().getValue().isNeedToShow());
       
    }
```

For this, I am getting a `null pointer exception` and I put the debugger and checked when I am passing data to showProgressBar function is getting called but not executing it goes to the last line directly.

I have tried this option as well

```
@Test
    public void testCdfwInProgress() {
        ActivityMainViewModel activityMainViewModel = Mockito.mock(ActivityMainViewModel.class);

        activityMainViewModel.showProgressBar("123", "123", 10,
                "IN_PROGRESS");

        Mockito.verify(activityMainViewModel, Mockito.timeout(12 * 1000).
                atLeast(1)).equals(activityMainViewModel.getCdfwData().getValue());

        Mockito.verify(activityMainViewModel, Mockito.timeout(12 * 1000).
                atLeast(1)).equals(activityMainViewModel.getCdfw().getValue());
    }
```

but getting this error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
activityMainViewModel.getCdfwData();
-> at cerence.assistant.reference.app.ui.activity.main.ActivityMainViewModel.getCdfwData
```

How do I write test cases for this method? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You should decide what you need to Test. Because you are trying to mock the same  object that you need to test.  It does not make any sense.

You should not to mock the object that you need to test. You should mock object's dependencies.

For example if you have a class:

```
class ViewModel(datamanager : Datamanager){

    fun doSomething(){
       datamanager.loadSomedata()
    }
}
```

If you want to test `ViewModel` class you should mock it's dependency: `DataManager`.

Test will be look like:

```
@Test
fun testDoSomething() {
   val manager = mock<DataManager>()
   val viewModel = ViewModel(manager). // Please note: that we don't need to mock ViewModel

   viewModel.doSomething()

   verify(manager).loadSomedata()
}
```

in this case you are testing `ViewModel` and you mock it's dependency(`DataManager`) you do not mock `ViewModel`.

in your case:

```
@Test
    public void testCdfwInProgress() {
        ActivityMainViewModel activityMainViewModel = ActivityMainViewModel() // here you should use a real object, not a mock.

        activityMainViewModel.showProgressBar("123", "123", 10,
                "IN_PROGRESS");

        Assert.assertSame(true,activityMainViewModel.getCdfw().getValue().isNeedToShow());
       
    }
```

Here you can find documentation with some samples:
https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.11.2/org/mockito/Mockito.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't have a dependency in the view model as you can see that function in the question. When I got some data from the view I will update the object according to and set it to live data. So here what I am trying to achive once that function is called I want to verify the live data object whether it is as per the data or not. Is it correct way to test that function ?

Comment: I've updated answer, and attached testCdfwInProgress() code sample at the end.

Comment: I tried your method but I am getting NPE at the line of assert true

Comment: Because cfdv is null. Try to call cdfw = cdfwData somewhere after when viewModel is created. I'm talknig about this line : var cdfw: MutableLiveData<Cdfw> = cdfwData

Comment: try to call cdfw = cdfwData means do I need to initialize it? do I need to assign some mock value to cdfw live data?

Comment: No, in this case problem not in the test code, the problem in the real code. I mean your viewModel code.